# How do you filter for rows in a table where the count is highest in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have a table called "Service" that has an integer field called "num_views". Is there a simple query that can be done in django that returns all of the Services in order from those that have the highest number of views.

For example I would like to do something like this:

```
services_by_views = Service.objects.filter(< ALL SERVICES ORDERED BY HIGHEST VIEW COUNT>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`order_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) specifying a *descending order*:

```
Service.objects.order_by('-num_views')
```